# Como cerrar una aplicacion Java/Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Buenas noches programadores,
Estoy desarrollando una app en android studio mediante java y estoyy intentando cerrar mi aplicacion una vez pasen 2 segundos despues de que se realice la llamada, pero la pestaña de la aplicacion sigue abierta luego de finalizar la llamada.

Adjunto codigo de referencia

```
    // Realizo una llamada
    if(true){
        String dial = "tel:" + number;
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial)));
        // Aqui intento cerrar mi aplicacion despues de 2 segundos realizada la llamada
        closeApp(2000);
    }
        
    public void closeApp(int millis){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(millis);
            Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
            super.onDestroy();
        }catch (Exception e) { }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, primero que nada agradecer sus respuestas.

Lo resolví de la siguiente forma:
En AndroidManifest.xml agregue la siguiente linea de codigo para darle transparencia al MainActivity.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

Posteriormente a eso, utilice `finish()` y `System.Exit()` para finalizar el proceso.

Gracias por sus respuestas

Answer (score 3):

Ojo, no he tenido tiempo de analizar ni probar tu método de cierre, aunque si ha quedado alguna activity abierta, quizás te venga el problema por ahí

De todas formas, te pongo un nuevo método para que puedas cerrar tu aplicación después de dos segundos

Prueba con:

```
else{
    String dial = "tel:" + number;
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial)));

    // Aqui intento cerrar mi aplicacion despues de 2 segundos realizada la llamada. Para ello creamos un evento Handler que tedrás que importar (import android.os.Handler;)
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //aquí, llamamos al método de cierre después de esperar los dos sgundos (2000) si quisieras aumentar el tiempo sería incrementar esa cifra
            metodoCerrar();
        }
    }, 2000);
}

public void metodoCerrar()
{
    //aquí cerramos el actícity actual
    finish();
    //creamos un nuevo intent de action_main para el cierre de todo lo que esté abierto
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Desde API 21 ademas de eliminar el proceso tambien puedes usar `finishAndRemoveTask();`que elimina todas las actividades.

> [finishAndRemoveTask()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.AppTask#finishAndRemoveTask()) Finaliza todas las actividades de esta
> tarea y la quita de la lista de tareas recientes.

Me parece que tu pregunta esta mas orientada a eliminar la "prevista" que se mantiene al finalizar una aplicacion al dar clic en el siguiente boton:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Las previstas de las aplicaciones no se pueden eliminar programaticamente, unicamente se pueden eliminar de forma manual.**

Answer (score 0):

Yo para cerrar una app creada por mi , simplemente con el siguiente comando lo realizo perfectamente ( debes adaptarlo a tus necesidades )

System.exit(0);